# Most efficient way to keep count of past minute events

Tags: python, time

I need a live running counter of a certain event that occurred in the past X MINUTES.

The below pseudocode accomplishes what I am trying to do, but in a very inefficient manner.  If I make the `WINDOW` 10 minutes (600 seconds) and lots of events happen, the below code becomes heavy to run!

```
import time
import random

WINDOW = 20 #time, in seconds, for which we want to sum events before they expire

event = list()

while True:
    #REMOVE FROM THE `event` list the elements more than 20 seconds old
    event = [i for i in event if i+WINDOW>time.time()]

    # Randomly make events happen
    if random.randint(1,100)<50:
        event.append((time.time()))
    time.sleep(.5)

    #Once every 10 seconds, print on screen the number of events that happened in the past 20 seconds
    if round(time.time()) % 10 ==0:
        print(f'We have {len(event)} events in the past {WINDOW} seconds')
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You can try using a [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-objects) of fixed size.

Comment: Fixed size would imply a constant number of events kept in record, not the count of events that happened in the past X seconds.  I do not even want to keep the events, only their count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reverse iteration and cut the list when the first old event is found:

```
tim=time.time()  # called only once
for idx in range(len(events)-1,-1,-1):
    if events[idx]+WINDOW<= tim:
        events[:idx+1]=""
        break
```